# ggplot2 faceting settings; x axis and colour

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm working on a graphic in ggplot2. I work with weevils and oaks. I'm trying to illustrate how does the acorn size changes the chance of being or not infested by weevils in two oak species. So I have a scatterplot with the logistic regression for each species (I used facet_grid()) and a histogram of the frequency of sound and infested acorns for each species too.

My problem is that the acorn sizes are really different and **I would like to change the x axis range only in one scatterplot and histogram** to avoid having one species compacted, but I don't know how to do it.

Also, I'm having problems **changing the colours for the histograms**. I tried putting the color directly in geom_histogram(... aes(fill="#HEXcode")) and with fill_color_brewer() argument.

This is how my script looks like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

g2 <- ggplot(Infestation, aes(x=Volumen, y=Situacion, color=Especie, alpha=1/density)) +
geom_point(size=3)+
scale_alpha(range = c(.05, .25))+
stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), se=TRUE)+
theme(legend.position="none")+
facet_grid(.~Especie)

g4 <- ggplot(Infestation, aes(x=Volumen))+
geom_histogram(data=subset(Infestation, Situacion %in% 0), aes(fill=as.factor(Situacion), alpha=0.5))+
geom_histogram(data=subset(Infestation, Situacion %in% 1), aes(fill=as.factor(Situacion), alpha=0.5))+
theme(legend.position="none")+  
facet_grid(.~Especie)

grid.arrange(g2,g4, nrow=2)
```

The figure looks like this: 
[image: graphic]

Also, if you have some amazing ideas to find alternatives ways to illustrate why I am trying to show, are gladly welcomed.

Thanks!

**Solved**

If anyone have a similar problem, here's the code.

```
LogReg <- ggplot(Infestation, aes(x=Volumen, y=Situacion, 
alpha=1/density)) +
geom_point(size=3, aes(fill=as.factor(Situacion), color=as.factor(Situacion)))+
scale_alpha(range = c(.05, .25))+
stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), se=TRUE, colour="black")+
theme(legend.position="none")+
facet_grid(.~Especie, scale="free_x")+
scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1", direction=1)

InfHist <- ggplot(Infestation, aes(x=Volumen))+
geom_histogram(aes(fill=as.factor(Situacion)), alpha = 0.75, position = "identity")+
theme(legend.position="none")+  
facet_grid(.~Especie, scales="free_x")+
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", direction = 1)

grid.arrange(LogReg,InfHist, nrow=2)
```

[image: graphicsolved]

Comment: Have you tried `facet_grid(.~Especie, scales = "free_x")`?

Comment: I actually think your figure looks pretty good. I would keep the same color scheme in both plots (ie, have the same color mean infestation status in each, not coding it to species in the top one). In the bottom one, you can replace both `geom`s with `geom_histogram(aes(fill=as.factor(Situacion)), alpha = 0.5, position = "identity")`. I also think keeping the x axis the same for both species is better than having them differ, but you could argue that either way. For a "good-bad" outcome, I particularly like `scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", direction = -1)`.

Comment: Thanks both for the help! 
@Brian I will let my thesis advisor decide about the axis. Keeping them make it more easily comparable, but I think I can lose some info if I have one species compressed to one side. 
The idea of mantaining the same color for infested and not infested in both plots is great, but now I don't know how to change that in the points of the scatterplot and keep the same color for the predictor line in both plots. Any ideas?

Comment: I already solved it. I'll post the code if anyone need to know how to do it.